# What is the difference of rollback and recover method of JMS session?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

JMS Session interface has two similar methods: rollback and recover. They are used in different ack mode: rollback in transaction and recover in client ack. But except that, what is the main difference of these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

rollback: tells the broker that current client will not process current message(s). Broker policy then dictates if it will redeliver to the same (or other) consumer or roll the messages to a dead letter queue

recover: instructs the broker to redeliver all unacknowledged messages to the current session

Comment: So if there are multi consumers to one destination. The rollback may make the broker redeliver the message to other consumers. But the recover will always make the broker redeliver the message to the current consumer. It is one of different behaviors. Correct?

Comment: Depends on the relationship between the connection -> session -> consumer objects. If the consumers are children of the same session (within the same running JVM process), then the rollback / recover impacts all consumers. If the consumers are children of different sessions, then the rollback / recover is just for a given session+consumer pair.  Make sense?